# Warning "Must be one of" - NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-lint

In Android Studio I get an error on `new NotificationChannel()`:

> Must be one of: android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH, android app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW, ...

But I reference exactly this.
So it seems this is a bug in Android Studio.
Does anyone have the same problem?

**Example:**
[image]

And I know I can add an `@Suppress` annotation, but I want to clarify if it is an error or not.

**CompileSDKVersion:** 26
**TargetSDKVersion:** 26
**Android Studio Version:** 3.0.1

**My Import:**
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What's your target and compile sdk version?

Comment: compile: 26, target 26, android studio 3.0.1

Comment: And you're sure you imported the `NotificationManager` class from the `android.app` package? Does it work with other `IMPORTANCE_*` values?

Comment: Yes of course. I have edit my post with the import statement. All IMPORTANCE_* are not working.

Comment: Same issue here using `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` but still giving red underline

Comment: For those less interested in why it's broken, use `@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")` to make it go away.

Comment: same error....used andy's way to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

There's a [bug reported in Android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68369502) about this.

Haven't looked into this in detail (and don't have Android tools on this computer right now) but it might have something to do with the fact that [`@Importance` `IntDef` is annotated with `@hide`](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/NotificationManager.java#186) and is therefore not included in the SDK.

Comment: It's only hidden so we can't annotate our own variables with it. The constant and the method parameter are both annotated so there should be no warning.